# OOZIE 4.2.0 Start-up Error: Exception = Could not authenticate, Authentication failed, status: 404, message: Not Found

Tags: oozie

I have configured and built ooze 4.2.0 with the following components
* Hadoop - 2.6.0
* OS     - Mac 10.7
* Hive   - 1.1.2
* Hbase  - 1.2.1
The embedded tomcat version with the ooze distort is **6.0.43**. As per ooze install and config instructions the server should run at **localhost:11000/oozie** , but I am getting the below error when I am starting ooze and checking the status of oozie.

Command (I have removed the http:// as I am not allowed more than 2 links in question)
**oozie admin -oozie localhost:11000/oozie -status**

**Exception = Could not authenticate, Authentication failed, status: 404, message: Not Found**

My **ooze-site.xml** configuration is as below

```
    <property>
        <name>oozie.system.id</name>
        <value>oozie-iMac</value>
        <description>The Oozie system ID.</description>
    </property>

<property>            
    <name>oozie.service.AuthorizationService.security.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>Specifies whether security is enabled or not.
                 If disabled any user can manage Oozie system and manage any job. 
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.kerberos.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>Indicates if Oozie is configured to use Kerberos.</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.authentication.type</name>
    <value>simple</value>
    <description> Defines Authentication used for Oozie HTTP endpoint.
                  Supported values: simple|kerberos|#AUTHENTICATION_HANDLER_CLASSNAME#
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.services</name>
    <value>
        org.apache.oozie.service.SchedulerService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.InstrumentationService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.MemoryLocksService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.UUIDService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.ELService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.AuthorizationService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.UserGroupInformationService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.JobsConcurrencyService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.URIHandlerService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.DagXLogInfoService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.SchemaService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.LiteWorkflowAppService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.JPAService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.CallbackService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.ActionService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.ShareLibService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.ActionCheckerService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.RecoveryService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.PurgeService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.CoordinatorEngineService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.BundleEngineService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.DagEngineService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.CoordMaterializeTriggerService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.StatusTransitService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.PauseTransitService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.GroupsService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.ProxyUserService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.XLogStreamingService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.JvmPauseMonitorService,
        org.apache.oozie.service.SparkConfigurationService
    </value>
    <description>
        All services to be created and managed by Oozie Services singleton.
        Class names must be separated by commas.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.db.schema.name</name>
    <value>oozie</value>
    <description> Oozie DataBase Name </description>
</property>
```

```
<property>
    <name>oozie.service.JPAService.jdbc.driver</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    <description> JDBC driver class. </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.JPAService.jdbc.url</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/oozie?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
    <description> JDBC URL. for MySQL DB connection </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.JPAService.jdbc.username</name>
    <value>oozie</value>
    <description> DB user name. </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>oozie.service.JPAService.jdbc.password</name>
    <value>oozie</value>
    <description> DB user password (leave 1 blank space if empty) </description>
</property>

<!-- Added as per Apache OOZIE Install documentation -->

<property>
   <name>oozie.service.JPAService.create.db.schema</name>
   <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>oozie.service.JPAService.validate.db.connection</name>
   <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>oozie.service.JPAService.pool.max.active.conn</name>
   <value>10</value>
</property> 

<property>
   <name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.keytab.file</name>
   <value>http.keytab</value>
   <description>Location of the Oozie user keytab file</description>
</property>
```

**core-site.xml**

```
  <property>
     <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
     <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>

    <property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.hosts</name>
     <value>*</value>
     <description> Proxy User Setup for Oozie runs </description>
    </property>

  <property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.groups</name>
     <value>*</value>
     <description> Proxy Group configuration for Oozie Run 
    </description>
  </property>
```

When I open the browser and type the same address it shows the error as below
[Tomcat Error on Safari Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Czl7.png)

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Could you please add the Startup log in oozie-server.

Comment: @karthik - The issue is resolved now, I re-built the Oozie distro and it all ran smoothly, after the build I didnot find any issues as above. Thanks for asking though.